# Bias to uniform class weka resample filter

Tags: java, filter, classification, filtering, weka

I am doing a data science project. My dataset is an imbalanced dataset. I am using Weka for classification purpose.

The dataset has 1273 instances. Among them yes class instances are 174 and No class instances are 1099. Therefore, the dataset is bias to no class.

I am using resample filter to maintain a ratio among yes class and no class. I am sharing a result below.

The parameter that I have tweaked to see various `yes: no` ratio is `bias to uniform class`. As per weka's documentation the definition of term `bias to uniform class` is `Whether to use bias towards a uniform class. A value of 0 leaves the class distribution as-is, a value of 1 ensures the class distribution is uniform in the output data.`

```
Result:

experiment result   bias to uniform ratio     yes    no   imbalance ratio
   1.                 0.5                     405    867  1:2
   2.                 0.75                    520    752  1:1.44
   3.                 0.25                    289    983  1:3.4
   4.                 1.0                     636    636  1:1
```

If I add all the yes and no instances it would return 1272

```
 405+867=1272
 520+752=1272
 289+983=1272
 636+636=1272
```

I have observed few more features about the data like,

If I subtract experiment 1 yes and no class from original yes and no class I got 1099-867=232 and 405-174 = 231. So the result of subtraction is similar.

If I subtract experiment 2 yes and no class from original yes and no class I got 1099-752 = 347 and 520-174= 346, again they are similar and so on.

I could not find out what is the relationship between the various value of bias to uniform class and the similar subtraction result.

Another thing I observed that if I change the value of `bias to uniform class` from 0 to 1.5 No class had less instances than yes class. What I mean to say

```
           bias to uniform class  yes  no      
 Experiment 5  1.5                867  405
```

You can see that here is more yes class instances than no class. It seems like the instances bias toward yes class.

So I believe I could not really understand what is the meaning of `bias to uniform class`.

If someone explain it clearly that would be helpful for my project.

One explanation I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874645/resample-filter-of-weka-how-to-interpret-the-result) on stackoverflow and this is not my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you have a problem with the output of the filter. Maybe the following will make it apparent to you how the filter functions.

Here is your data in one table, slightly rearranged:

```
experiment result   bias to uniform ratio     yes    no   imbalance ratio
   0.                 0.0                     174   1099  1:6.3
   3.                 0.25                    289    983  1:3.4
   1.                 0.5                     405    867  1:2
   2.                 0.75                    520    752  1:1.44
   4.                 1.0                     636    636  1:1
   5.                 1.5                     867    405  1:0.47
```

**NB:** Experiment 0 is simply your original data, which I added to make it the progression clearer, when changing the `bias to uniform class (distribution)` parameter.

This bias parameter simple means how much the class distribution in the output data is leaning towards a uniform class distribution.

As per documentation, `1.0` gives you a uniform distribution (`1:1`).

What you can see from the above table is that increasing the bias parameter will decrease the ratio of the `no` label. As soon as the value goes above `1.0`, it will put more emphasis on the other class label (i.e., `yes`).

The [createSubsample()](https://github.com/Waikato/weka-trunk/blob/7df22fbee30195a63e7780f2f4bcd3c8bbf3ffd4/weka/src/main/java/weka/filters/supervised/instance/Resample.java#L529) method in the Resample filter applies the user-supplied bias factor.

Comment: I still cannot understand. class distribution means yes and no class distribution. Output data means 289/983, 405/867, 520/752... etc right? What do you mean by uniform class distribution? Can you explain `This bias parameter simple means how much the class distribution in the output data is leaning towards a uniform class distribution.` again?

Comment: A balanced dataset has a uniform class (label) distribution.